# How to make an Ajax/Cors request to a webDav storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, webdav

I'm trying to write a javascript/jquery plugin to access a webDav storage with JSON-data only and am struggling to get it to work.

The webDav will be a remote storage, so I need to make a cross-domain ajax request, passing along authentication data.

I have tried various versions, but I'm always failing on the `preflight` authentication, while I can access the file correctly, when I enter the URL in the browser directly (and provide login credentials).

This is what I have tried:

```
$.ajax({
  url: priv.url + '/' + priv.user + '/' +
    priv.foldertree + '/' + docid,
  type: "GET",
  async: true,
  crossdomain : true,
  headers : {
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(
      priv.user + ':' + priv.password
      )
  },
  success: function (content) {
    console.log( content );
  }
});
```

I have also set the following without luck:

```
 xhrFields: {withCredentials: 'true'}
 contentType: 'text/plain'
```

or:

```
 datatype: "jsonp"
```

or:

```
 username: priv.user
 password: priv.password
```

or:

```
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 
      "Basic" + Base64.encode( priv.user + ':' + priv.password )
    );
  }
```

but all I'm gettin is a `401` `authorization failed` response from the remote server on my `preflight options` request.

**Question:**
I don't have access to the remote server, but since it's a remote WebDav Storage-as-a-Service, it should be possible to access the files I'm planning to store there. Can someone give me a pointer on how to correctly make a request to GET my JSON data (I will also need to post, propfind, remove, but first things first...)?

Thanks!

Comment: check this url http://enable-cors.org

Comment: @salexch: on the client "coming soon"? I'm also working with the HTML5 rocks article, so I'm still kinda stuck.

Comment: you have a link there to test live.. with a code

Comment: ok, tried it a couple of times. Still doesn't work. Should/could be webDav provider settings?

Comment: is your javascript webdav client open source?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: yes. It's called [jio](http://www.j-io.org/) and I'm one of the authors. The documentation is still lacking a little but we are using JIO in all of our projects, plus currently doing a large rewrite. So let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Provider settings did not allow to use webDAV/Ajax/preflight/authentication.

Switched provider ([Otixo](http://www.otixo.com)) - now it works.

Comment: if you make your comment an answer, I will check. Thx

Comment: no thanks :) this link can go away.. and its not seems to be a valid  or full answer..