# Ajax jQuery request to a webDav storage with auth?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, webdav

already found something here:
[How to make an Ajax/Cors request to a webDav storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317387/how-to-make-an-ajax-cors-request-to-a-webdav-storage/19566798#19566798)
But i need COMPLETE html/php/script
I tried for 2 days around now..

**Can anyone provide me a complete solution to access webdav with auth with ajax?**

Comment: The most important question of all - does your provider support it. if you can't answer that, then you should begin this first.

Comment: Note that if by "webdav request" you mean "PROPFIND request" you're out of luck. Web browsers dont permit PROPFIND requests. Unless you use a server like http://milton.io which has a built in ajax/webdav gateway. If you just need to do a GET thats not webdav, its just HTTP, and all the usual HTTP stuff applies